# XBox One S Wireless Controller Possibly Invalid HID Descriptor

Tags: bluetooth, usb, hid, usb-hid

I have been trying to connect my ESP-32 microcontroller to an XBox One S Wireless controller via classic bluetooth using [this BTStack implemented by Bluekitchen](https://github.com/bluekitchen/btstack). I have managed to connect the two devices (with the ESP-32 as the host) and can read all the values from the controller on the ESP-32. I am now trying to work out how to send valid reports to the controller. The descriptor reported by the controller upon connection is this:

```html
05 01 09 05 A1 01 85 01 09 01 A1 00 09 30 09 31 15 00 27 FF FF 00 00 95 02 75 10 81 02 C0 09 01 A1 00 09 33 09 34 15 00 27 FF FF 00 00 95 02 75 10 81 02 C0 05 01 09 32 15 00 26 FF 03 95 01 75 0A 81 02 15 00 25 00 75 06 95 01 81 03 05 01 09 35 15 00 26 FF 03 95 01 75 0A 81 02 15 00 25 00 75 06 95 01 81 03 05 01 09 39 15 01 25 08 35 00 46 3B 01 66 14 00 75 04 95 01 81 42 75 04 95 01 15 00 25 00 35 00 45 00 65 00 81 03 05 09 19 01 29 0A 15 00 25 01 75 01 95 0A 81 02 15 00 25 00 75 06 95 01 81 03 05 01 09 80 85 02 A1 00 09 85 15 00 25 01 95 01 75 01 81 02 15 00 25 00 75 07 95 01 81 03 C0 05 0F 09 21 85 03 A1 02 09 97 15 00 25 01 75 04 95 01 91 02 15 00 25 00 75 04 95 01 91 03 09 70 15 00 25 64 75 08 95 04 91 02 09 50 66 01 10 55 0E 15 00 26 FF 00 75 08 95 01 91 02 09 A7 15 00 26 FF 00 75 08 95 01 91 02 65 00 55 00 09 7C 15 00 26 FF 00 75 08 95 01 91 02 C0 85 04 05 06 09 20 15 00 26 FF 00 75 08 95 01 81 02 C0
```

When I run this dump through [this translator](https://eleccelerator.com/usbdescreqparser/#), I get a readable output that is included at the end of the question since it is quite long. Only the output report format of the HID descriptor is listed here:

```html
0x05, 0x0F,        //   Usage Page (PID Page)
0x09, 0x21,        //   Usage (0x21)
0x85, 0x03,        //   Report ID (3)
0xA1, 0x02,        //   Collection (Logical)
0x09, 0x97,        //     Usage (0x97)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x01,        //     Logical Maximum (1)
0x75, 0x04,        //     Report Size (4)
0x95, 0x01,        //     Report Count (1)
0x91, 0x02,        //     Output (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x00,        //     Logical Maximum (0)
0x75, 0x04,        //     Report Size (4)
0x95, 0x01,        //     Report Count (1)
0x91, 0x03,        //     Output (Const,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x09, 0x70,        //     Usage (0x70)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x64,        //     Logical Maximum (100)
0x75, 0x08,        //     Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x04,        //     Report Count (4)
0x91, 0x02,        //     Output (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x09, 0x50,        //     Usage (0x50)
0x66, 0x01, 0x10,  //     Unit (System: SI Linear, Time: Seconds)
0x55, 0x0E,        //     Unit Exponent (-2)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,  //     Logical Maximum (255)
0x75, 0x08,        //     Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x01,        //     Report Count (1)
0x91, 0x02,        //     Output (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x09, 0xA7,        //     Usage (0xA7)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,  //     Logical Maximum (255)
0x75, 0x08,        //     Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x01,        //     Report Count (1)
0x91, 0x02,        //     Output (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x65, 0x00,        //     Unit (None)
0x55, 0x00,        //     Unit Exponent (0)
0x09, 0x7C,        //     Usage (0x7C)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,  //     Logical Maximum (255)
0x75, 0x08,        //     Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x01,        //     Report Count (1)
0x91, 0x02,        //     Output (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0xC0,              //   End Collection
```

My understanding of the HID standard would indicate that this part of the descriptor is invalid, since `Usage (0x70)` is followed by `Report Count (4)`, the btstack parser that I am using to debug why this isn't working then has to try to match 4 bytes to a single usage and isn't able to do this as far as I am aware. Currently the report I am trying to send to the controller (and to the parser, while I am debugging) is `0x03, 0xF0, 0x64, 0x64, 0x64, 0x64, 0xFF, 0x10, 0x05`, where the `0x03` indicates the report ID, and the following values indicate parameters I am sending to control rumble motors. The 4 `0x64` values are the 4 bytes that should be mapped to 4 usages, however only correspond to 1 usage `0x70` according to the HID Descriptor. At the moment the parser stops after finding the first `0x64` and claims to be finished.

Am I wrong in thinking this HID Descriptor is invalid? If I am, does anyone know what report I should be sending to match this HID Descriptor template. Sorry for the messiness/length of this question.

Thanks in advance,
Richard

**Full Readable HID Descriptor Output:**

```html
0x05, 0x01,        // Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
0x09, 0x05,        // Usage (Game Pad)
0xA1, 0x01,        // Collection (Application)
0x85, 0x01,        //   Report ID (1)
0x09, 0x01,        //   Usage (Pointer)
0xA1, 0x00,        //   Collection (Physical)
0x09, 0x30,        //     Usage (X)
0x09, 0x31,        //     Usage (Y)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x27, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00,  //     Logical Maximum (65534)
0x95, 0x02,        //     Report Count (2)
0x75, 0x10,        //     Report Size (16)
0x81, 0x02,        //     Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0xC0,              //   End Collection
0x09, 0x01,        //   Usage (Pointer)
0xA1, 0x00,        //   Collection (Physical)
0x09, 0x33,        //     Usage (Rx)
0x09, 0x34,        //     Usage (Ry)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x27, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00,  //     Logical Maximum (65534)
0x95, 0x02,        //     Report Count (2)
0x75, 0x10,        //     Report Size (16)
0x81, 0x02,        //     Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0xC0,              //   End Collection
0x05, 0x01,        //   Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
0x09, 0x32,        //   Usage (Z)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x26, 0xFF, 0x03,  //   Logical Maximum (1023)
0x95, 0x01,        //   Report Count (1)
0x75, 0x0A,        //   Report Size (10)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x00,        //   Logical Maximum (0)
0x75, 0x06,        //   Report Size (6)
0x95, 0x01,        //   Report Count (1)
0x81, 0x03,        //   Input (Const,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x05, 0x01,        //   Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
0x09, 0x35,        //   Usage (Rz)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x26, 0xFF, 0x03,  //   Logical Maximum (1023)
0x95, 0x01,        //   Report Count (1)
0x75, 0x0A,        //   Report Size (10)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x00,        //   Logical Maximum (0)
0x75, 0x06,        //   Report Size (6)
0x95, 0x01,        //   Report Count (1)
0x81, 0x03,        //   Input (Const,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x05, 0x01,        //   Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
0x09, 0x39,        //   Usage (Hat switch)
0x15, 0x01,        //   Logical Minimum (1)
0x25, 0x08,        //   Logical Maximum (8)
0x35, 0x00,        //   Physical Minimum (0)
0x46, 0x3B, 0x01,  //   Physical Maximum (315)
0x66, 0x14, 0x00,  //   Unit (System: English Rotation, Length: Centimeter)
0x75, 0x04,        //   Report Size (4)
0x95, 0x01,        //   Report Count (1)
0x81, 0x42,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,Null State)
0x75, 0x04,        //   Report Size (4)
0x95, 0x01,        //   Report Count (1)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x00,        //   Logical Maximum (0)
0x35, 0x00,        //   Physical Minimum (0)
0x45, 0x00,        //   Physical Maximum (0)
0x65, 0x00,        //   Unit (None)
0x81, 0x03,        //   Input (Const,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x05, 0x09,        //   Usage Page (Button)
0x19, 0x01,        //   Usage Minimum (0x01)
0x29, 0x0A,        //   Usage Maximum (0x0A)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x01,        //   Logical Maximum (1)
0x75, 0x01,        //   Report Size (1)
0x95, 0x0A,        //   Report Count (10)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x00,        //   Logical Maximum (0)
0x75, 0x06,        //   Report Size (6)
0x95, 0x01,        //   Report Count (1)
0x81, 0x03,        //   Input (Const,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x05, 0x01,        //   Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
0x09, 0x80,        //   Usage (Sys Control)
0x85, 0x02,        //   Report ID (2)
0xA1, 0x00,        //   Collection (Physical)
0x09, 0x85,        //     Usage (Sys Main Menu)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x01,        //     Logical Maximum (1)
0x95, 0x01,        //     Report Count (1)
0x75, 0x01,        //     Report Size (1)
0x81, 0x02,        //     Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x00,        //     Logical Maximum (0)
0x75, 0x07,        //     Report Size (7)
0x95, 0x01,        //     Report Count (1)
0x81, 0x03,        //     Input (Const,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0xC0,              //   End Collection
0x05, 0x0F,        //   Usage Page (PID Page)
0x09, 0x21,        //   Usage (0x21)
0x85, 0x03,        //   Report ID (3)
0xA1, 0x02,        //   Collection (Logical)
0x09, 0x97,        //     Usage (0x97)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x01,        //     Logical Maximum (1)
0x75, 0x04,        //     Report Size (4)
0x95, 0x01,        //     Report Count (1)
0x91, 0x02,        //     Output (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x00,        //     Logical Maximum (0)
0x75, 0x04,        //     Report Size (4)
0x95, 0x01,        //     Report Count (1)
0x91, 0x03,        //     Output (Const,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x09, 0x70,        //     Usage (0x70)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x64,        //     Logical Maximum (100)
0x75, 0x08,        //     Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x04,        //     Report Count (4)
0x91, 0x02,        //     Output (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x09, 0x50,        //     Usage (0x50)
0x66, 0x01, 0x10,  //     Unit (System: SI Linear, Time: Seconds)
0x55, 0x0E,        //     Unit Exponent (-2)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,  //     Logical Maximum (255)
0x75, 0x08,        //     Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x01,        //     Report Count (1)
0x91, 0x02,        //     Output (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x09, 0xA7,        //     Usage (0xA7)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,  //     Logical Maximum (255)
0x75, 0x08,        //     Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x01,        //     Report Count (1)
0x91, 0x02,        //     Output (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x65, 0x00,        //     Unit (None)
0x55, 0x00,        //     Unit Exponent (0)
0x09, 0x7C,        //     Usage (0x7C)
0x15, 0x00,        //     Logical Minimum (0)
0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,  //     Logical Maximum (255)
0x75, 0x08,        //     Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x01,        //     Report Count (1)
0x91, 0x02,        //     Output (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0xC0,              //   End Collection
0x85, 0x04,        //   Report ID (4)
0x05, 0x06,        //   Usage Page (Generic Dev Ctrls)
0x09, 0x20,        //   Usage (Battery Strength)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,  //   Logical Maximum (255)
0x75, 0x08,        //   Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x01,        //   Report Count (1)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0xC0,              // End Collection
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you've found the issue, but this may be of interest to others. I decoded the HID descriptor with [hidrdd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hidrdd/) (which points out errors and suggests improvements). The result is as follows:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Report descriptor data in hex (length 306 bytes)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// 05010905 A1018501 0901A100 09300931 150027FF FF000095 02751081 02C00901
// A1000933 09341500 27FFFF00 00950275 108102C0 05010932 150026FF 03950175
// 0A810215 00250075 06950181 03050109 35150026 FF039501 750A8102 15002500
// 75069501 81030501 09391501 25083500 463B0166 14007504 95018142 75049501
// 15002500 35004500 65008103 05091901 290A1500 25017501 950A8102 15002500
// 75069501 81030501 09808502 A1000985 15002501 95017501 81021500 25007507
// 95018103 C0050F09 218503A1 02099715 00250175 04950191 02150025 00750495
// 01910309 70150025 64750895 04910209 50660110 550E1500 26FF0075 08950191
// 0209A715 0026FF00 75089501 91026500 5500097C 150026FF 00750895 019102C0
// 85040506 09201500 26FF0075 08950181 02C0   


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Decoded Application Collection
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
05 01        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
09 05        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010005 Game Pad (Application Collection)  
A1 01        (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x01 Application (Usage=0x00010005: Page=Generic Desktop Page, Usage=Game Pad, Type=Application Collection)
85 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x01 (1)  
09 01          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010001 Pointer (Physical Collection)  
A1 00          (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x00 Physical (Usage=0x00010001: Page=Generic Desktop Page, Usage=Pointer, Type=Physical Collection)
09 30            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010030 X (Dynamic Value)  
09 31            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010031 Y (Dynamic Value)  
15 00            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
27 FFFF0000      (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x0000FFFF (65535)  
95 02            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x02 (2) Number of fields  
75 10            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x10 (16) Number of bits per field  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (2 fields x 16 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0             (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Physical 
09 01          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010001 Pointer (Physical Collection)  
A1 00          (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x00 Physical (Usage=0x00010001: Page=Generic Desktop Page, Usage=Pointer, Type=Physical Collection)
09 33            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010033 Rx (Dynamic Value)  
09 34            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010034 Ry (Dynamic Value)  
15 00            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
27 FFFF0000      (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x0000FFFF (65535) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MAXIMUM is already 65535 
95 02            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x02 (2) Number of fields <-- Redundant: REPORT_COUNT is already 2 
75 10            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x10 (16) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 16 
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (2 fields x 16 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0             (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Physical 
05 01          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page <-- Redundant: USAGE_PAGE is already 0x0001
09 32          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010032 Z (Dynamic Value)  
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
26 FF03        (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x03FF (1023)  
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields  
75 0A          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x0A (10) Number of bits per field  
81 02          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 10 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x00 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 25 00 with 24
75 06          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x06 (6) Number of bits per field  
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields <-- Redundant: REPORT_COUNT is already 1 
81 03          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000003 (1 field x 6 bits) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
05 01          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page <-- Redundant: USAGE_PAGE is already 0x0001
09 35          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010035 Rz (Dynamic Value)  
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
26 FF03        (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x03FF (1023)  
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields <-- Redundant: REPORT_COUNT is already 1 
75 0A          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x0A (10) Number of bits per field  
81 02          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 10 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x00 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 25 00 with 24
75 06          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x06 (6) Number of bits per field  
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields <-- Redundant: REPORT_COUNT is already 1 
81 03          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000003 (1 field x 6 bits) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
05 01          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page <-- Redundant: USAGE_PAGE is already 0x0001
09 39          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010039 Hat switch (Dynamic Value)  
15 01          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x01 (1)  
25 08          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x08 (8)  
35 00          (GLOBAL) PHYSICAL_MINIMUM   0x00 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 35 00 with 34
46 3B01        (GLOBAL) PHYSICAL_MAXIMUM   0x013B (315)  
66 1400        (GLOBAL) UNIT               0x0014 Rotation in degrees [1° units] (4=System=English Rotation, 1=Rotation=Degrees)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 66 1400 with 65 14
75 04          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x04 (4) Number of bits per field  
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields <-- Redundant: REPORT_COUNT is already 1 
81 42          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000042 (1 field x 4 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 1=Null 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
75 04          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x04 (4) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 4 
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields <-- Redundant: REPORT_COUNT is already 1 
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x00 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 25 00 with 24
35 00          (GLOBAL) PHYSICAL_MINIMUM   0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: PHYSICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 35 00 with 34
45 00          (GLOBAL) PHYSICAL_MAXIMUM   0x00 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 45 00 with 44
65 00          (GLOBAL) UNIT               0x00 No unit (0=None)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 65 00 with 64
81 03          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000003 (1 field x 4 bits) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
05 09          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0009 Button Page 
19 01          (LOCAL)  USAGE_MINIMUM      0x00090001 Button 1 Primary/trigger (Selector, On/Off Control, Momentary Control, or One Shot Control)  
29 0A          (LOCAL)  USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x0009000A Button 10 (Selector, On/Off Control, Momentary Control, or One Shot Control)  
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 01          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)  
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field  
95 0A          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x0A (10) Number of fields  
81 02          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (10 fields x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x00 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 25 00 with 24
75 06          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x06 (6) Number of bits per field  
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields  
81 03          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000003 (1 field x 6 bits) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
05 01          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
09 80          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010080 System Control (Application Collection)  
85 02          (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x02 (2)  
A1 00          (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x00 Physical (Usage=0x00010080: Page=Generic Desktop Page, Usage=System Control, Type=Application Collection) <-- Warning: USAGE type should be CP (Physical Collection)
09 85            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010085 System Main Menu (One Shot Control)  
15 00            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 01            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)  
95 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields <-- Redundant: REPORT_COUNT is already 1 
75 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
15 00            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 00            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x00 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 25 00 with 24
75 07            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x07 (7) Number of bits per field  
95 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields <-- Redundant: REPORT_COUNT is already 1 
81 03            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000003 (1 field x 7 bits) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0             (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Physical 
05 0F          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000F Physical Interface Device Page 
09 21          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000F0021 Set Effect Report (Logical Collection)  
85 03          (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x03 (3)  
A1 02          (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x02 Logical (Usage=0x000F0021: Page=Physical Interface Device Page, Usage=Set Effect Report, Type=Logical Collection)
09 97            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000F0097 DC Enable Actuators (Selector)  
15 00            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 01            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)  
75 04            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x04 (4) Number of bits per field  
95 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields <-- Redundant: REPORT_COUNT is already 1 
91 02            (MAIN)   OUTPUT             0x00000002 (1 field x 4 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
15 00            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 00            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x00 (0)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 25 00 with 24
75 04            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x04 (4) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 4 
95 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields <-- Redundant: REPORT_COUNT is already 1 
91 03            (MAIN)   OUTPUT             0x00000003 (1 field x 4 bits) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
09 70            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000F0070 Magnitude (Dynamic Value)  
15 00            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 64            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x64 (100)  
75 08            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field  
95 04            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x04 (4) Number of fields  
91 02            (MAIN)   OUTPUT             0x00000002 (4 fields x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
09 50            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000F0050 Duration (Dynamic Value)  
66 0110          (GLOBAL) UNIT               0x1001 Time in seconds [1 s units] (1=System=SI Linear, 1=Time=Seconds)  
55 0E            (GLOBAL) UNIT_EXPONENT      0x0E (Unit Value x 10⁻²)  
15 00            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
26 FF00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x00FF (255)  
75 08            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 8 
95 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields  
91 02            (MAIN)   OUTPUT             0x00000002 (1 field x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
09 A7            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000F00A7 Start Delay (Dynamic Value)  
15 00            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
26 FF00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x00FF (255) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MAXIMUM is already 255 
75 08            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 8 
95 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields <-- Redundant: REPORT_COUNT is already 1 
91 02            (MAIN)   OUTPUT             0x00000002 (1 field x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
65 00            (GLOBAL) UNIT               0x00 No unit (0=None)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 65 00 with 64
55 00            (GLOBAL) UNIT_EXPONENT      0x00 (Unit Value x 10⁰)  <-- Info: Consider replacing 55 00 with 54
09 7C            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000F007C Loop Count (Dynamic Value)  
15 00            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
26 FF00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x00FF (255) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MAXIMUM is already 255 
75 08            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 8 
95 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields <-- Redundant: REPORT_COUNT is already 1 
91 02            (MAIN)   OUTPUT             0x00000002 (1 field x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0             (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Logical 
85 04          (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x04 (4)  
05 06          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0006 Generic Device Controls Page 
09 20          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00060020 Battery Strength (Dynamic Value)  
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
26 FF00        (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x00FF (255) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MAXIMUM is already 255 
75 08          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field <-- Redundant: REPORT_SIZE is already 8 
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields <-- Redundant: REPORT_COUNT is already 1 
81 02          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (1 field x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0           (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application 
*/

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Generic Desktop Page inputReport 01 (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x01 (1)
                                                     // Collection: CA:GamePad CP:Pointer
  uint16_t GD_GamePadPointerX;                       // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = 0 to 65535
  uint16_t GD_GamePadPointerY;                       // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = 0 to 65535
  uint16_t GD_GamePadPointerRx;                      // Usage 0x00010033: Rx, Value = 0 to 65535
  uint16_t GD_GamePadPointerRy;                      // Usage 0x00010034: Ry, Value = 0 to 65535
                                                     // Collection: CA:GamePad
  uint16_t GD_GamePadZ : 10;                         // Usage 0x00010032: Z, Value = 0 to 1023
  uint8_t  : 6;                                      // Pad
  uint16_t GD_GamePadRz : 10;                        // Usage 0x00010035: Rz, Value = 0 to 1023
  uint8_t  : 6;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  GD_GamePadHatSwitch : 4;                  // Usage 0x00010039: Hat switch, Value = 1 to 8, Physical = (Value - 1) x 45 in degrees
  uint8_t  : 4;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton1 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090001: Button 1 Primary/trigger, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton2 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090002: Button 2 Secondary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton3 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090003: Button 3 Tertiary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton4 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090004: Button 4, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton5 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090005: Button 5, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton6 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090006: Button 6, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton7 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090007: Button 7, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton8 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090008: Button 8, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton9 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090009: Button 9, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton10 : 1;                  // Usage 0x0009000A: Button 10, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 6;                                      // Pad
} inputReport01_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Generic Desktop Page inputReport 02 (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x02 (2)
                                                     // Collection: CA:GamePad CP:SystemControl
  uint8_t  GD_GamePadSystemControlSystemMainMenu : 1; // Usage 0x00010085: System Main Menu, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 7;                                      // Pad
} inputReport02_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Generic Device Controls Page inputReport 04 (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x04 (4)
                                                     // Collection: CA:GamePad
  uint8_t  GEN_GamePadBatteryStrength;               // Usage 0x00060020: Battery Strength, Value = 0 to 255
} inputReport04_t;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Physical Interface Device Page outputReport 03 (Device <-- Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x03 (3)
                                                     // Collection: CA:GamePad CL:SetEffectReport
  uint8_t  PID_GamePadSetEffectReportDcEnableActuators : 4; // Usage 0x000F0097: DC Enable Actuators, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 4;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  PID_GamePadSetEffectReportMagnitude[4];   // Usage 0x000F0070: Magnitude, Value = 0 to 100
  uint8_t  PID_GamePadSetEffectReportDuration;       // Usage 0x000F0050: Duration, Value = 0 to 255, Physical = Value in 10⁻² s units
  uint8_t  PID_GamePadSetEffectReportStartDelay;     // Usage 0x000F00A7: Start Delay, Value = 0 to 255, Physical = Value in 10⁻² s units
  uint8_t  PID_GamePadSetEffectReportLoopCount;      // Usage 0x000F007C: Loop Count, Value = 0 to 255
} outputReport03_t;
```

The report descriptor seems to be generally OK. I could optimise it down from 306 bytes to just 191 bytes - representing exactly the same data flows (see below).

As for the 0x70 usage, it looks to me like there are 4 actuators which can be enabled using the 4-bit DcEnableActuators usage (0x97). So I would guess that you should be sending:

```
0x03, 0x0F, 0x64, 0x64, 0x64, 0x64, 0xFF, 0x10, 0x05
```

in order to enable all 4 of them instead of:

```
0x03, 0xF0, 0x64, 0x64, 0x64, 0x64, 0xFF, 0x10, 0x05
```

Just for fun, here is an optimised version of the report descriptor that they could have used instead:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Report descriptor data in hex (length 191 bytes)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// 05010905 A1018501 0901A100 09300931 09330934 1427FFFF 00009504 75108102
// C0093226 FF039501 750A8102 24750681 03093526 FF03750A 81022475 06810309
// 39150125 0834463B 01651475 04814214 24446481 03050919 01290A25 01750195
// 0A810224 75069501 81030501 09808502 A1000985 25017501 81022475 078103C0
// 050F0921 8503A102 09972501 75049102 24910309 70256475 08950491 02095066
// 0110550E 26FF0095 01910209 A7910264 54097C91 02C08504 05060920 8102C0
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the controller had disabled the vibration motors since the battery was "low", and sending the report described in the question (with a 0xA2 at the start) worked as I intended it to when I had replaced the batteries. I'm still not sure if the HID Descriptor is actually syntactically valid, but the controller does what I want it to now at least!